# Android Apps one time login from Setting Add Accounts

Tags: android, single-sign-on, android-authenticator

I would like the user of my app to add their account from Setting->Accounts->Add Account, then they have login forever.

Or, is it possible to allow the user to pick one of the accounts from Setting->Accounts as user account for my app?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)?

Comment: This blog article will tell you what you need to know: http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/